# What do abbreviations L.E., L.C. and D.N.I. mean in Spanish

Tags: abreviaturas, argentina

What do the abbreviations L.E., L.C., and D.N.I. mean in Argentinian Spanish?
They seem related to car registrations.

Answer (score 8):

Acording to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documento_Nacional_de_Identidad_%28Argentina%29):

> **Documento Nacional de Identidad** or **DNI** (which means National Identity Document) is the main identity document for Argentine citizens, as well as temporary or permanent resident aliens.
>
> ...
>
> Before the introduction of the DNI in 1968, women had a **Libreta cívica** [**LC**] ("civic booklet"); men a **Libreta de enrolamiento** [**LE**] ("(military) enrollment booklet").

Comment: I won't write an answer myself because this is perfectly OK, but I would add that people with LC and LE kept those for a long while (they didn't disappear in 1968), and they can still be found in e.g. electoral rolls. The government did encourage everyone with those IDs to switch to DNIs during the past decade or so.

Comment: And there even was a C.I. (cédula de identidad, or identity card) which was a valid identity document but, instead of being issued by the Civil Registry Office, was issued by the Police Department. It coexisted for a long time with the DNI/LC/LR, but while the CI only served the purposes of attesting identity, the others were required for voting as well as for registering other details which could be written on their pages (they were actual booklets). Nowadays the DNI is only a card.